# How to format a decimal number as currency.

Tags: java, jsp, number-formatting

I wanted to write price for the product in vector using number format. Here is my code

```
<%!
        class product
        {
            public String name;
            public int price;
            public String image;

            public product()
            {
            }
        }
    %>
<%
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setCurrencySymbol("$ ");
    dfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    dfs.setMonetaryDecimalSeparator('.');
    ((DecimalFormat) nf).setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);


    Vector<product> vec = new Vector<product>();
    gallery obj;

    obj=new product();
    obj.nama="Dark Chocolate";
    obj.price=Integer.parseInt(nf.format(3040000));
    obj.image="Image/Dark chocolate.jpg";
    vec.add(obj);

    obj = new product();
    obj.nama="Woodhouse Chocolates";
    obj.price=Integer.parseInt(nf.format(6000500));
    obj.image="Image/woodhouse_chocolates.jpg";
    vec.add(obj);

    obj = new product();
    obj.name="Semisweet Chocolate";
    obj.price=Integer.parseInt(nf.format(3050000));
    obj.image="Image/Semisweet chocolate.jpg";
    vec.add(obj);

    obj = new product();
    obj.name="White Chocolate";
    obj.price=Integer.parseInt(nf.format(2948000));
    obj.image="Image/White chocolate.jpg";
    vec.add(obj);

%>
```

It said

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page

at this section

```
 obj.price=Integer.parseInt(nf.format(3040000));
 obj.price=Integer.parseInt(nf.format(6000500));
 obj.price=Integer.parseInt(nf.format(3050000));
 obj.price=Integer.parseInt(nf.format(2948000));
```

Where's my the mistake? Could anyone help me?

Comment: What do those numbers (3040000, 6000500, 3050000, 2948000) represent? Are those dollar values? I.e., three million dollar chocolate?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to format a number with a bunch of random characters *THEN* trying to parse it into an Integer.

That will not work.

[An Integer](http://www.techterms.com/definition/integer) is a whole number that has no decimal portion and no fancy characters.

Any character other than 0-9 (or a negative sign) will throw a NumberFormatException if you try to parse it as an Integer.

... and (like *iangreen* says) you should put your code in a try block.

... *AND* (like *iangreen* says) you could easily move this code somewhere else where you can test/debug it a *LOT* easier (IDE or console program).

... *AND* you should always begin class names with a capital letter.

---

Given the fact that you're trying to format your prices before you create your products, you should store them in your product class as Strings.  *OR* you could store them as doubles or floats and format them at another time.

Answer (score 2):

This makes absolutely no sense. You're trying to format the integer into a human readable `String` and then parsing it back to `int` which would in theory cause all formatting to be lost. The `int` can't store the format. It should be stored in `String`. But, the moment when you're doing that is wrong, it should be done during presentation, not during preprocessing. You shouldn't have `String`s hanging around with the format.

Use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<fmt:formatNumber>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html).

```html
<fmt:formatNumber value="${product.price}" type="currency" currencyCode="USD" />
```

It'll format it in standard USD format and automagically prefix the `$` currency symbol.

I'd also change `int` to `BigDecimal` otherwise you can't speak about a real price format. You cannot store and present fractions in an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your code in a try/catch and print the exception out.
better yet - move your code into a java class and write a unit test so you can execute it quickly in an IDE